# visual proof of the chinese remainder theorem?

Tags: number-theory, visualization

I have seen visual proofs for fermats little theorem, gauss sum and many other things. I find them very useful. Is there a visual proof for the chinese remainder theorem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which visual proofs have you seen? Any links or references?

Comment: I really don't see how Fermat's little theorem could be made "visual"... just read up the proof and it's an identity that works, but maybe someone got original. I'd be interested in a visual proof for Fermat's.

Comment: Patrick Da Silva: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPMzosLWGHo , and here is a formal proof running with that idea: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Bishop.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccccc}
 & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \pmod 5
\\\hline
\\ & 0 & 0 & 6 & 12 & 3 & 9
\\ \pmod 3 & 1 & 10 & 1 & 7 & 13 & 4
\\ & 2 & 5 & 11 & 2 & 8 & 14
\end{array}$$

Comment: Fine, it's a grid... I don't see how that helps! Maybe the OP disagrees with me but anyway.

Comment: I think, it's visual. $0,1,2,3,..$ written in the diagonal, continuously. Pairs of remainders mod 3 and 5 are corresponded to remainder mod 15.

Comment: **Danger** often lurks behind a "visual" proof @Berci, e,g,

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccccc}
           & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &\rm (mod\ 6)
\\\hline
\\         & 0 & 0 &  & 8 &  & 4
\\ \pmod 4 & 1 &  & 1 &  & 9 & & 5
\\         & 2 & 6 &  & 2 &  & 10
\\         & 3 &  & 7 &  & 3 & & 11
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Hurkyl Could you please explain _why_ the grid supposedly proves the CRT? How is the grid and the diagonal alignment of certain numbers a proof of anything?

Comment: @BillDubuque So, maybe one could say that the grid needs to be filled entirely?